# Failed to connect to server through PXE

Tags: ubuntu, boot

Cannot connect client to server (see attach.[image])

in a few minutes got message "DHCP received no offers!". 
this is my dhcp.conf on server

```
#
# Sample configuration file for ISC dhcpd for Debian
#
# Attention: If /etc/ltsp/dhcpd.conf exists, that will be used as
# configuration file instead of this file.
#
#

# The ddns-updates-style parameter controls whether or not the server will
# attempt to do a DNS update when a lease is confirmed. We default to the
# behavior of the version 2 packages ('none', since DHCP v2 didn't
# have support for DDNS.)
ddns-update-style none;

# option definitions common to all supported networks...
option domain-name "example.org";
option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.60;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

# If this DHCP server is the official DHCP server for the local
# network, the authoritative directive should be uncommented.
authoritative;

# Use this to send dhcp log messages to a different log file (you also
# have to hack syslog.conf to complete the redirection).
log-facility local7;

# No service will be given on this subnet, but declaring it helps the 
# DHCP server to understand the network topology.

#subnet 10.152.187.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
#}

# This is a very basic subnet declaration.

#subnet 10.254.239.0 netmask 255.255.255.224 {
# range 10.254.239.10 10.254.239.20;
# option routers rtr-239-0-1.example.org, rtr-239-0-2.example.org;
#}

# This declaration allows BOOTP clients to get dynamic addresses,
# which we don't really recommend.

#subnet 10.254.239.32 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
# range dynamic-bootp 10.254.239.40 10.254.239.60;
# option broadcast-address 10.254.239.31;
# option routers rtr-239-32-1.example.org;
#}

# A slightly different configuration for an internal subnet.
subnet 192.168.1.60 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.1.30 192.168.1.120;
# option domain-name-servers ns1.internal.example.org;
# option domain-name "internal.example.org";
# option subnet-mask 255.255.255.224;
option routers 192.168.1.60;
# option broadcast-address 10.5.5.31;
# default-lease-time 600;
# max-lease-time 7200;
filename="ubuntu/install/netboot/pxelinux.0";
}

# Hosts which require special configuration options can be listed in
# host statements. If no address is specified, the address will be
# allocated dynamically (if possible), but the host-specific information
# will still come from the host declaration.

#host passacaglia {
# hardware ethernet 0:0:c0:5d:bd:95;
# filename "vmunix.passacaglia";
# server-name "toccata.fugue.com";
#}

# Fixed IP addresses can also be specified for hosts. These addresses
# should not also be listed as being available for dynamic assignment.
# Hosts for which fixed IP addresses have been specified can boot using
# BOOTP or DHCP. Hosts for which no fixed address is specified can only
# be booted with DHCP, unless there is an address range on the subnet
# to which a BOOTP client is connected which has the dynamic-bootp flag
# set.
#host fantasia {
# hardware ethernet 08:00:07:26:c0:a5;
# fixed-address fantasia.fugue.com;
#}

# You can declare a class of clients and then do address allocation
# based on that. The example below shows a case where all clients
# in a certain class get addresses on the 10.17.224/24 subnet, and all
# other clients get addresses on the 10.0.29/24 subnet.

#class "foo" {
# match if substring (option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 4) = "SUNW";
#}

#shared-network 224-29 {
# subnet 10.17.224.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
# option routers rtr-224.example.org;
# }
# subnet 10.0.29.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
# option routers rtr-29.example.org;
# }
# pool {
# allow members of "foo";
# range 10.17.224.10 10.17.224.250;
# }
# pool {
# deny members of "foo";
# range 10.0.29.10 10.0.29.230;
# }
#}
```

ifconfig of server:

```
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:48:1c:16:ab:19  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:254 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:574 errors:1 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:73982 (73.9 KB)  TX bytes:93643 (93.6 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:6001 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6001 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:499008 (499.0 KB)  TX bytes:499008 (499.0 KB)

wlo1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:18:8b:cc:41:09  
          inet addr:192.168.1.60  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2074:6e2b:49be:277c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:64333 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:54185 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:63862865 (63.8 MB)  TX bytes:10043170 (10.0 MB)
```

ifconfig of client:

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 1c:75:08:f5:7e:62 
inet6 addr: fe80::1e75:8ff:fef5:7e62/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:173 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:246 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:36691 (36.6 KB) TX bytes:49110 (49.1 KB)
Interrupt:16 

lo Link encap:Локальная петля (Loopback) 
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
RX packets:297 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:297 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
RX bytes:28316 (28.3 KB) TX bytes:28316 (28.3 KB)

wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 88:9f:fa:19:76:c7 
inet addr:192.168.1.45 Bcast:192.168.1.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
inet6 addr: fe80::8a9f:faff:fe19:76c7/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:1004 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:197 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:130953 (130.9 KB) TX bytes:25928 (25.9 KB)
```

What should I change to make it work?

P.S.
computers connected through Ethernet

Comment: Why is there no IP address on the server `eno1` interface? If that is the ethernet interface...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistakes I've seen (I probably overlooked a few):

- Ethernet doesn't have assigned IP address
- Your `dhcp.conf` uses the address range on the wlan interface instead
- subnet description is not zeroed in netmask (the subnet should be 192.168.1.**0** with mask 255.255.255.0)
- the assigned range overlaps with the IP addr of the DHCP server
- I'm not sure if it's necessary for PXE, but `allow booting;` and `allow bootp;` lines in the `dhcp.conf` dont' hurt.
- Your domain-name-servers option won't work unless you actually offer DNS (which you probably don't), but as it's not needed for PXE, it won't hurt.

So:

- Pick a private subnet different from your WLAN, e.g. `192.168.22.0`.
- Let's keep `192.168.22.30` to `192.168.22.120` for the assigned DHCP address.
- The address of the DHCP server must be outside, let's choose `192.168.22.1`.
- Assign this address to `eno1` with `ip addr add 192.168.22.1/24 dev eno1`.
- Make the changes to `dhcp.conf`, restart `dhcpd`.

and try again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but how can I do this "The address of the DHCP server must be outside, let's choose 192.168.22.1" ? 
And why it is gonna work if I change the range to 192.168.22.30 to 192.168.22.120 if my client has 192.168.1.45?

Comment: Thank you very much, dirkt! 
I have done like you said and it seemed to be solved! But I got next errors, which is connected to previous one. After booting I got this lines:
Client Ip: 192.168.22.30 Mask 255.255.255.0
Gateway Ip: 192.168.22.1
PXE-E11: Arp timeout
PXE-E38: TFTP cannot open connection
and then booting normally....
How should I correct it?

Comment: 192.168.1.45 is the IP address for the **WLAN** interface of your client. The client will receive an IP address for the **ethernet** interface from the DHCP server.

Comment: You need to setup a TFTP server with the PXE boot image. Have you done this at all?

Comment: yes, I did this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323516/setup-of-tftp-to-boot-os-from-pxe/323552#323552

Comment: maybe the problem is in the line: filename="ubuntu/install/netboot/pxelinux.0"; in /etc/ltsp/dhcpd.conf ? I just copied it from manual and honestly have no idea what does it mean..