# Setup of TFTP to boot OS from PXE

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to network system from network using PXE. I almost done, but have some problem.
When I boot my client from PXE I got this on clients' screen:
PXE-E11: ARP timeout
PXE-E38: TFTP cannot open connection

There are some attempts on the Internet to fix it, but nothing concrete, so I will describe my case in details.

in this file /etc/default/atftpd I changed 
**USE_INETD=true** 
to 
**USE_INETD=false**
then in the file `/etc/default/tftpd-hpa`

I put TFTP_DIRECTORY="/srv/tftp", because srv/tftp was in the end of file `/etc/default/atftpd`.

Then I run `sudo /etc/init.d/atftpd start`

and few last things I typped `sudo mount -o loop /home/tux/ubuntu16-Desktop.iso /srv/tftp/ubuntu/`
 and done with tftp, but it does not work.

Do you have ideas to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I would say check your DHCP configuration for this subnet. Assuming you're running your DHCP server separately from your TFTP server, you should have `next-server` set to the correct TFTP address (or DNS record, providing the `option domain-name-servers` is also set correctly in DHCP). It might be worth checking that the `filename` option is set appropriately too.

Also, check that the correct permissions are set on the TFTP directory.

Comment: maybe the problem is in the line: filename="ubuntu/install/netboot/pxelinux.0"; in  /etc/ltsp/dhcpd.conf ? I just copied it from manual and honestly have no idea what does it mean..

Comment: That line points to the PXE boot file and it's very much needed. Here's a useful link for setting up diskless Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto

Comment: Thank you for this link! Here I also  see unknown reference  filename "/pxelinux.0"; in dhcpd.conf... I understand it is important, but what this path should be in my case? and where I can get this pselinux.0 in order to put it somewhere on my server?

Comment: I have no pxelinux.0 on my computer, that seems to be the problem... Maybe I should download .iso which supports .pxe boot?

Comment: You'll need to install the `syslinux` package and copy the file from the appropriate directory. It's in the instructions via the link provided.